# Переключение чекбокса не отражается на кнопке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не получается настроить переключение активности кнопки, код вроде правильно написан.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  function(e) {
    if ($('#pers_data').is(":checked")) {
      $("#send_but").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#send_but").css("background", "#191919");
    } else {
      $("#send_but").attr('disabled', "disabled");
      $("#send_but").css("background", "#6B6B6B");
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><input type="checkbox" id="pers_data"> Я согласен на обработку персональных данных (<a href="#" style="color:#0988AE;">соглашение</a>).</span>


<button id="send_but" type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="button">Отправить</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так-то надо слушатель добавлять на изменение состояния чекбокса:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#pers_data').on('change', function(){

    if ($('#pers_data').is(":checked")) {
      $("#send_but").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $("#send_but").attr('disabled', "disabled");
    }

  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><input type="checkbox" id="pers_data"> Я согласен на обработку персональных данных (<a href="#" style="color:#0988AE;">соглашение</a>).</span>
<button id="send_but" type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="button">Отправить</button>
```